# Parsing a zero value from CSV

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I'm trying to import some data from a CSV file into a WordPress plugin.

I'm having trouble when the value to be imported is '0'. Currently it converts a '0' to NULL when saved in the database. The idea is to import a sport score ie. 2-0, which then gets parsed into an array.

```
$score = explode( '-', $result );

$home = trim($score[0]);
$away = trim($score[1]);

$goals = array( 'total' => array( 'home' => $home, 'away' => $away) );

update_post_meta( $id, 'total_score', serialize( $goals ) );
```

Can anybody suggest a solution, knowing me it's probably something blindingly obvious but my brain has hit a brick wall!

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you suer its **0** and not blank

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I've checked and double checked the input and it is definitely a 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue :)

The original code was correct but a dodgy if/else statement was preventing the value for `$score` parsing correctly.

The answers below, although not used, did help me slim down the possibilities, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
$home = strval(trim($score[0]));
$away = strval(trim($score[1]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @michael but I have fixed the problem. The problem was elsewhere but your suggestion helped me get there - thanks again!